# How to go to an other activity after clicking on one slit of the pie chart

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to build a part of my app that has a pie chart but my problrm is how to click on one part of the pie-chart and go to an other activity here is my code it display the pie-chart but the application stops when I click on one of the pie chart parts to go to the other activity .
I managed to create the pie-chart its working fine but when I go to insert the intent part it stops . 
Advanced help would be appreciated !

Comment: When you go to another activity and application stops then what does it throw error ?

Comment: Share your code so  we can help

Comment: Thank you but it works fine now I corrected it .

Comment: @haouasrim What was the issue ?

Comment: @Piyush : the problem was with the onchartSelected methods I put the intent in a wrong place . now its working thak you for your answer anyway .

Comment: @haouasrim Okay ! Cool